# sticky footer on IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

Can't get sticky footer working on IE11.. Chrome looks good. Pretty sure the problem here is `min-height`, just can't find the way around it (need to keep the html structure intact, no wrappers, just css changes).

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html style="height:100%">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body style="height:100%;background:grey">
    <div style="height:100%">
      <div style="min-height:100%;background:white;display:flex;flex-direction:column">
        <header style="background:green">hello</header>
        <main>me mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome main</main>
        <footer style="background:yellow;margin-top:auto">sticky footer</footer>
      </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

https://jsbin.com/lonotadara

**EDIT:** 
Left is chrome, right is IE11:

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what behavior you want here. Do you want the footer to be visible at the bottom of the viewport?

Comment: Right now it works fine on Chrome, just not on IE11.

Comment: I don't see a "sticky" footer in your code snippet, and the code you provided looks identical on both Chrome and IE from what I see. Is my answer what you are going for?

Comment: @Nick added some pics, does that help?

Comment: @TylerH added more info.

Comment: I think you're out of luck if you cannot change the HTML structure. This has been a well-known issue with IE, and IE is no longer being developed. Your best bet is to see if any of the solutions [here](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) solve your issue, but I think it's unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could use the follownig code to make it work in IE too.

CSS

```
    <style>
    html {
        display: flex;
    }

    body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .header {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        background: green;
    }
    .footer {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        background: yellow;
    }

    .content {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<header class="header">hello</header>
<main class="content">me mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome mainsome main</main>
<footer class="footer">sticky footer</footer>
```

[image: wroking in IE]